# how to solve Unison 2.48\n" but received "grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface (v1.2.0)

Tags: docker, unison

1. I use docker and unison.
2. I follow step by step in
   https://www.mgt-commerce.com/documentation/mgt-development-mac-file-synchronization.
3. I am forget to run file synchronisation before I run grunt on my
   project use SSH.
4. after I run grunt on my ssh project and start file synchronisation. some trouble show like this one.

   Fatal error: Received unexpected header from the server:
    expected "Unison 2.48\n" but received "grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface (v1.2.0)\n", 
   which differs at "g".
   This can happen because you have different versions of Unison
   installed on the client and server machines, or because
   your connection is failing and somebody is printing an error
   message, or because your remote login shell is printing
   something itself before starting Unison.

I have to try troubleshooting from mgt-commerce[dot]com/documentation/mgt-development-mac-file-synchronization.
but didn't works and try to uninstall my unison still didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should take this up with MGT-Commerce support, really. Possibly you are using the wrong URL or host name.

When Unison connects to a host, it launches the `unison` executable on that host. It then tries to establish contact with that executable running on the remote host.

In this case, Unison is complaining because it can't find a `unison` executable to talk to. In particular, an executable called `grunt-cli` is replying instead.

You could try troubleshooting this problem yourself by doing the following:

```
ssh root@127.0.0.1 unison -version
```

That should print something like

```
unison version 2.40.63
```

(Version numbers may differ.) If you don't see a message like this, this indicates that Unison can't be found on the remote host. The exact error message should give you some hints.